# Common factor in series solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

a few times during my lectures on series solutions ( to ODE) the teacher mentioned that it was only valid to use all the theorems and methods and such on analytic polynomials if they did not have a common factor (x-c). The examples of which I am referring to are mostly in regard to being able to assume that the ODE has a power series solution of the form $$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n}$$

But I am having trouble finding an example of where this is a problem and why?

Is there any good example that shows why it won't work as such and we must divide out?

I mean would this make something not analytic for example? If anyone has link/example to this that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What theorems? I think you should clarify.

Comment: Okay I added one

Comment: Still no theorem, so I guess: Maybe you find out something good from [Frobenius method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method), in the bottom. If so, I guess you can come up with an example where the roots of the indicial equation are repeated... You could look at Bessel's equation, for noninteger $n$, see the article on [Bessel functions on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Answer (score 0):

An example of what I write about in the comment (but elementary), and hopefully what you ask for:
$$
4t^2x''(t)-8t^2x'(t)+(4t^2+1)x(t)=0,\quad t>0
$$
The indicial equation is $\lambda(\lambda-1)+1/4=0$, with double root $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1/2$. Then,
$$
x(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k t^{k+1/2}
$$
with $a_0=1$ will give you $a_k=1/k!$, so you get a solution
$$
x(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} t^{1/2}\frac{t^k}{k!}=t^{1/2}e^t.
$$
The other basis solution is easily found (let $y(t)=t^{1/2}e^t x(t)$, with $x$ the solution above) to be $t^{1/2}e^t\ln t$, so the general solution to the differential equation is
$$
x(t)=(A+B\ln t)t^{1/2}e^t.
$$